# Application of function that produces new column based on other Dataframe Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, boolean

Im trying to write a function takes the X Coordinate from an existing column and multiplies it by negative 1 if certain conditions are met. The function compiles fine, but I keep getting hit with the `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` error message once I apply it to the column of interest.

My function:

```
def xCoordFlip(xCoord):
  for xCoord in df['xCoord']:
    if df.loc[(df.period == 2) & (df.period == 4) & (df.name == 'A')]:
      return df['xCoord'] *-1
    if df.loc[(df.period == 1) & (df.period == 3) & (df.name == 'A')]:
      return df['xCoord']
    if df.loc[(df.period == 2) & (df.name == 'B')]:
      return df['xCoord'] *-1
    if df.loc[(df.period == 1) & (df.period == 3) & (df.name == 'B')]:
      return df['xCoord']
```

Basically I want to write a function that takes an X Coordinate and flips it if certain conditions are met. I'm guessing my understanding of Boolean conditions and their applications is way off, so any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using "and" instead of "&" right now you're using bitwise and instead of a boolean and

Actually it looks like I am wrong here.

[Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

This seems to answer your question well.

Comment: I tried that earlier, got the same error message when I applied it to the dataframe column

Comment: I found that question when trying to figure out what went wrong, having trouble understanding how exactly I apply it in my function